# How to slide a word in a sentence in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible, using css or Javascript to silde a word in a sentence? I've the below, for sliding text. When the second sentence is shown, the word 'Data' to be then replaced with Process, then Technology, then Formula. Until all the words are shown the next sentence should not be shown.

Tried using `setInterval`, get the display text from the `div` using `innerText`
and write conditions to remove/re-add class. But, `innerText` always giving all the text inside the div.

HTML:

```
<div class="tag-slider">
    <div class="marquee down" id="marquee-down-text">
        <p>Manage collaborative process</p>
        <p>Three level security to protect your Data</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee.down p {
    transform:translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
}

.marquee.down p:nth-child(1) {
    animation: down-one 10s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: down-one 10s ease infinite;
    -webkit-animation: down-one 10s ease infinite;
}

.marquee.down p:nth-child(2) {
    animation: down-two 10s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: down-two 10s ease infinite;
    -webkit-animation: down-two 10s ease infinite;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the word `Data` into `<span>` element and animate it instead of `<p>`

Comment: can you post your javascript too?

Comment: hey Matthias S. you will find a lot of solutions to this if you search for 'word carousel' or  'word slider' on codepen or on other coder websites. there you can inspect the code and get into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this via CSS-animations:

```css
.sliding-words-wrapper {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* set height to fit one item */
  height: 18.4px;
}

.sliding-words {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide-words 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide-words {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    /* (Word count - 1) * 100% */
    top: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-slider">
  <div class="marquee down" id="marquee-down-text">
    <p>Manage collaborative process</p>
    <div>Three level security to protect your
      <div class="sliding-words-wrapper">
        <div class="sliding-words">
          <span>Data</span>
          <span>Process</span>
          <span>Technology</span>
          <span>Formula</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to show this animation after some event (e.g. showing text) you can set its state to paused (via CSS property `animation-play-state: paused`), then after some event to `animation-play-state: running` via JavaScript.